# Find string in Json

Tags: json, vb.net

Here's what I want to do.

I have a json string that looks something like this:

```
{
"id":1,
"description":"my description 1",
},
{
"id":2,
"description":"my description 2",
},
...
```

I deserialize that with the following code (Its VB.Net but I can port it to C#):

```
Dim result As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Json.txt")
Dim json As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Object)(result)
```

Now the part where I get stuck.
My Program has a TextBox and a Button.
I want to be able to enter text (the id, for example "1") into that textbox, and when I Press the button it searches in that Json String for the ID "1" and outputs the description of it.

I search for "1" and it outputs "my description 1".

How could I do that?

Comment: Create a class that represents this data, any it only gets easier from there. Right now it's just an object...

Comment: How do I do that. Any references?

Comment: `Public Class MyItem
        Public Property id As Integer
        Public Property description As String
    End Class` that should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what language you want it in, but this is what you need to do.

1. Create a class that represents the objects you are going to deserialze.
2. Deserialze the string to a List of the object type.
3. Use Linq to select the appropriate description.

I have chosen to use Newtonsoft to deserialize here but you can choose whatever.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

For the actual finding of the appropriate result.

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
var objectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(json);

//Replace the 1 with the textboxSearch.Text accordingly
var foundItem = objectList.Where(_ => _.Id == "1").FirstOrDefault();

if (foundItem != null)
    MessageBox.Show(foundItem.Description);
//You can do whatever you want with the object here
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution. Thank you, this works flawless!